# Comando IN() no mysql com C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Ola, estou com um problema que não consigo resolver. Quero fazer um `SELECT` na base usando o comando `IN(@grupo)`. Onde o *@grupo* é uma string com os ids separados por virgula exp(1,2,4). Porem quando eu executo o sql ele considera apenas o primeiro valor (1) e não todos os valores.

esse é o SQL que estou utilizando

```
 public List<PedidoPDVMODEL> BuscaGrupoDistribuidores(string grupo)
    {
        SuportePDV s = new SuportePDV();


        //cria uma lista para os parametros
        List<SuportePDV.SQLParametro> parametros = new List<SuportePDV.SQLParametro>();
        parametros.Add(new SuportePDV.SQLParametro("@grupo", grupo));

        //monta a query
        string query = "SELECT SUM(total) AS total, dt_pedido " +
                       "FROM tpedido " +
                       "WHERE IN(@grupo) AND YEAR(dt_pedido) > 2015 AND dt_cancela = '0000-00-00' " +
                       "GROUP BY MONTH(dt_pedido), YEAR(dt_pedido) " +
                       "ORDER BY dt_pedido";

        DataTable tabela = s.RetornaDataTable(query, parametros);
        List<PedidoPDVMODEL> lista = new List<PedidoPDVMODEL>();

        if (tabela.Rows.Count == 0)
            return lista;

        try
        {
            foreach (DataRow item in tabela.Rows)
            {
                PedidoPDVMODEL g = new PedidoPDVMODEL
                {
                    dt_pedido = Convert.ToDateTime(item["dt_pedido"].ToString()),
                    total = Convert.ToDecimal(item["total"].ToString()),
                    mes = Convert.ToDateTime(item["dt_pedido"].ToString()).Month,
                    ano = Convert.ToDateTime(item["dt_pedido"].ToString()).Year
                };

                lista.Add(g);
            }

            return lista;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + ex.Message, "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: você vai precisar construir esse parâmetro com o separador e fazer o tratamento no MySQL. Apresente o código c# de como está realizando a consulta

Comment: Obrigado por responder, onde eu posso inserir o código para você visualizar. Eu sou novo aqui, ainda não pequei o jeito

Comment: Eu editei a postagem com o código que estou usando. Eu recebo uma string "grupo", e nela tem os ids dos grupos que desejo buscar